# Subiquity install network assignment

Tags: boot, networking, subiquity

I'm using Packer and trying to set the Subiquity network information at the boot prompt.  This snippet works with the 20.04.4 ISO, but not with the 22.04 beta ISO.  22.04 gets me networking from the DHCP server instead of the static settings I'd like to use for the installation.  Is something else required other than this, e.g., user-data settings?

```
  "boot_command": [
    "<enter><enter><f6><esc><wait>",
    "locale=en_US ",
    "biosdevname=0 ",
    "net.ifnames=0 ",
    "vga=791 ",
    "autoinstall ",
    "hostname=ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64 ",
    "ip=192.168.1.251::192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0:ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64:eth0:off:192.168.1.1 ",
    "ds=nocloud-net;s=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/files/cloud-init/ ",
    "PACKER_HOST={{ .HTTPIP }} ",
    "PACKER_PORT={{ .HTTPPort }} ",
    "<enter>"
  ],
```

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc. *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*